# ASP Net Core AJAX Post Sending NULL to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post data to a controller in ASP.NET Core
I receive null in the controller.

I can't get any data POSTed to an endpoint.

In the action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEarningg([FromBody] ProgramAddDTO program)
    {
        //_ProgramAppService.AddEarning(program);

        ViewData["tenantlist"] = ListItems();
        return View();
    }
```

In the ajax code:

```
<script src="~/Common/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
   

    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#SubProductCodeId").select2();
    $("#ProductId").select2();
    $("#ProductCodeId").select2();
    $("#ProductCodeId").select2();
    $("#CountryId").select2();
    $("#MerchantId").select2();
    $("#ChannelId").select2();
    $("#SegmentId").select2();
    $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
        var formdata = {};
        
        formdata.institutionId = $("#InstitutionId").val();
        formdata.programName = $("#ProgramName").val();
        formdata.productId = $("#ProductId").val();
        formdata.productCodeId = $("#ProductCodeId").val();
         formdata.subProductId= $("#SubProductId").val();
         formdata.TransactionTypeId= $("#TransactionTypeId").val();
         formdata.ChannelId= $("#ChannelId").val();
         formdata.SubProductCodeId= $("#SubProductCodeId").val();
         formdata.SpendToEarn= $("#SpendToEarn").val();
         formdata.EquivalnetPoint= $("#EquivalnetPoint").val();
         formdata.CountryId= $("#CountryId").val();
         formdata.MCCId= $("#MCCId").val();
         formdata.MerchantId= $("#MerchantId").val();
         formdata.SegmentId= $("#SegmentId").val();
         formdata.CapsMin= $("#CapsMin").val();
         formdata.CapsMax= $("#CapsMax").val();
        formdata.PointsExpiry = $("#PointsExpiry").val();
        var t = JSON.stringify(formdata)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/Program/AddEarningg',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'program': formdata }),
        
            success: function () {
                alert("test");
            }
        });
    });
       

    });     
</script>
```

in the DTO
ProgramAddDTO Class

```
public class ProgramAddDTO
{
    //public int? ProgramTypeId { get; set; }

    public int InstitutionId { get; set; }

    public string ProgramName { get; set; }

    public List<int?> ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> ProductCodeId { get; set; }

    public List<int?> SubProductId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> SubProductCodeId { get; set; }

    public List<int?> CountryId { get; set; }

    public int? TransactionTypeId { get; set; }

   
    public int EquivalnetPoint { get; set; }
   
    public int PointValue { get; set; }
    public List<int?> ChannelId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> MCCId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> MerchantId { get; set; }
    public List<int?> SegmentId { get; set; }

    public decimal CapsMin { get; set; }

    public decimal CapsMax { get; set; }

    public int? PointsExpiry { get; set; }

    public int SpendToEarn { set; get; }
}
```

When I pass a complex JSON to the post method, then it always shows me null.

I'm using the select2 jquery library.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ 'program': formdata }),` should be `data: JSON.stringify(formdata ),`

Comment: @Eldar not working in console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working by me when parse value from form to int

```
    var pinstitutionId =parseInt( $("#InstitutionId").val());
        var pprogramName = $("#ProgramName").val();
        var pproductId = $("#ProductId").val();
        var pproductCodeId = $("#ProductCodeId").val();
        var psubProductId= $("#SubProductId").val();
        var ptransactionTypeId= parseInt($("#TransactionTypeId").val());
        var pchannelId= $("#ChannelId").val();
        var psubProductCodeId= $("#SubProductCodeId").val();
        var pspendToEarn= parseInt($("#SpendToEarn").val());
        var pequivalnetPoint= parseInt($("#EquivalnetPoint").val());
        var pcountryId= $("#CountryId").val();
        var pmCCId= $("#MCCId").val();
        var pmerchantId= $("#MerchantId").val();
        var psegmentId= $("#SegmentId").val();
        var pcapsMin= parseInt($("#CapsMin").val());
        var pcapsMax= parseInt($("#CapsMax").val());
        var ppointsExpiry =parseInt( $("#PointsExpiry").val()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use Uppercase letters for your json properties. For example

```
formdata.TransactionTypeId
```

should become

```
formdata.transactionTypeId
```

and so one.

Because by default in .net core asp.net it looks for not capitalized json properties and it convert it to the correspondent property in C# that start with uppercase.

And the request should works simply with:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/app/Program/AddEarningg',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(formdata) ,

        success: function () {
            alert("test");
        }
```

Comment: for your int values you may need stuff like  parseInt($("#InstitutionId").val(),10);

Comment: In your json you should also surround everything that in the ProgramAddDTO class is a list with []. Like 
`formdata.ChannelId= $("#ChannelId").val();`
should be
`formdata.ChannelId= [$("#ChannelId").val()];`

I suggest to start trying to receive a json with only one property. For example comment all the properties in ProgramAddDTO and leave only 
the property `public int? TransactionTypeId { get; set; }`

and just pass a json with:
`{
        transactionTypeId: 1
    }`

Comment: Can you be more specific? You receive an exception? If you put a breakpoint in the action before it enters the action? You still have a null parameter?

Comment: @MattiasSantoro im puk a breakpoint in the action and i dont have any exception just the value null in action

Comment: @othmanjadallah Ok, what if replace the call with: `$.ajax({
        url: '/app/Program/AddEarningg',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { transactionTypeId: 1},

        success: function () {
            alert("test");
        }` 
No more referring formData anymore. If don't work try with `JSON.stringify({transactionTypeId: 1})`